# Is there any recent example (post 1990) of European high officials giving up special protection?

Tags: government, europe

According to [this article](http://www.nineoclock.ro/all-members-of-dancila-govt-give-up-spp-protection-to-protest-spp-directors-involvement-in-politics-publicly-denounced-by-liviu-dragnea/), virtually all Romanian cabinet members have given up the protection services offered by the Protection and Guard Service (SPP), which is designated for providing protection for high officials (e.g. President, Parliament Chamber heads):

> Premier Viorica Dancila gave up the SPP’s services right after she was
>   sworn in, the protection services being now offered by the Romanian
>   Gendarmerie.
>
> The decision to give up the SPP’s services was taken by all members of
>   the new Government.

No clear reason was provided for this and some analysts speculated a lack of trust, since head of SPP is appointed by the President as opposed to Gendarmerie which is controlled by Minister of Defense. Others have even said that such an act should not be allowed, since (some of) members of the cabinet have access to privileged information.

**Question:** Is there any recent example (post 1990) of European high officials giving up special (designated) protection?

Comment: In Sweden, there was a debate about personal security after the assassination of [Anna Lindh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Lindh). She wasn’t accompanied by a bodyguard at the time, but I’m not sure whether this was her own decision or that of the security police. Before [Olof Palme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olof_Palme) got assassinated, he himself had sent away his bodyguards, believing he wouldn’t need them; that was before 1990, though.

Comment: Seems they have not given up special protection completely in Romania but rather switched to a different provider of special protection?

Comment: @Trilarion - they actually switched it, but it is clear that the designated protection service is more competent at ensuring high official protection. Gendarmerie is usually involved in civil protection (e.g. protests, important sport events).